# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: bootbox

Tags: javascript, bootbox

I'm trying to use the Bootbox plugin, but I can't make it work, this is my import code:

```
    <script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="ui-bootbox.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

then HTML:

```
<p>Content here. <a class="alert" href=#>Alert!</a></p>
```

and Javascript:

```
    $(document).on("click", ".alert", function(e) {
        bootbox.alert("Hello world!", function() {
            console.log("Alert Callback");
        });
    });
```

But when I click the link, this is the error in the console:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: bootbox
```

how I can to fix this?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your `bootbox.js` is corrupted. Get a copy from the cdn. It should work.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".alert", function(e) {
  bootbox.alert("Hello world!", function() {
    console.log("Alert Callback");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootbox.js/4.4.0/bootbox.js"></script>
<p>Content here. <a class="alert" href=#>Alert!</a>
</p>
```